# Touchpad swipe gestures in Google Chrome on Linux?

Tags: chrome

Is it possible to set up Google Chrome in a way to have touchpad swipe gestures available?

For example, use two fingers and swipe to the right/left to navigate history.

Comment: There are several ways to configure shortcuts triggered by touch gestures. These may depend on the touchpad driver used (probably libinput) so you should check that first. Then you could configure the gestures to trigger mouse button 8 / 9 or ALT+Left / Right (chrome shortcut for back / forward)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures) seems to enable the functionality you want. The provided default gestures should contain all you need.